# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My code is a giveaway code with embed:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('!giveaway')) {
  const {MessageEmbed} = require ('discord.js')
  const args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1)
  let time = args[0]
  let prizeargs = message.content.split(' ').slice(2)
  let prize = prizeargs.join(" ")
  if (isNaN(time)) return;
  const embed1 = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('Giveaway started!')
  .setDescription(prize)
  .setFooter('Giveaway will resulted in ' + time + ' second.')
  const embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('Giveaway ended, winner: ' + message.guild.members.cache.random)
  .setDescription(prize)
  .setFooter('Congrats!')
  message.channel.send(embed1).then(embed => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      embed.edit(embed2)
    }, time * 1000);
  })
  }
})
```

and I am getting that error I don't know why heres the error:

```
(node:180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.title: Must be 256 or fewer in length.
embeds[0].title: Must be 256 or fewer in length.
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/paintest/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/runner/paintest/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14)
(node:180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:180) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Please help me how can I fix that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over here

```js
.setTitle('Giveaway ended, winner: ' + message.guild.members.cache.random)
```

`message.guild.members.cache.random` is a function and must be called. Change it to this:

```js
.setTitle('Giveaway ended, winner: ' + message.guild.members.cache.random())
```